# Open-source software that supports multi robot simulation and navigation capabilities

Tags: control, ros, motion-planning, simulation, multi-agent

I am interested in knowing a software platform which deals with multi-robot navigation and:-

1. has implemented local  collision  avoidance  algorithms for each robot to prevent collisions between robots
2. has independent controllers such as PID for each robot

Most likely such a framework will be in ROS or python. I am interested in open source codes such as those in github. The goal is to have a platform where a set of way-points can be assigned to each robot and they can avoid collisions and reach their way-points. At least this much ability should be already implemented.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user_1_1_1, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.